# Error in closure function when recursing over the list

Tags: recursion, closures

I've implemented a function but it doesn't seem to be going deep enough since it's not returning all the possible options.

And this my function and helper:

```
let closure n lst =
  iterate ( (a, x) -> a into (closure_helper n x)) lst)
```

I get 6.
what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code that determines what states can be reached from q, given a transition `(a, b, c)` and a list of other transitions `t`:

```
if a = q && b = None then 
   (c::(closure_helper delta c)) @ (closure_helper t q)
else
    closure_helper t q
```

Note that in general `delta` represents only the transitions not examined yet by `closure_helper`, not the full list of transitions. Thus when you find a new reachable state `c` you only look for further states by looking at a subset of the transitions.

So it seems to me.

Comment: Do you know how can you reexamine the whole delta list?

Comment: Pass the full list as an additional parameter.